# How to interpret console values that don't have any point to split on?

Tags: c#, split, console-application

I have a console application where I am imputing values. The attempt is to simulate a game where I have an object that moves forward, backward, right and left.

**The order in witch the object moves forward, backward left and right is the order the values are inputed in.**

These values are simple values such as:

```
Forward:  F 
Backward: B
Right:    R
Left:     L
```

The way I am inputing these values in the console is:

> F R B L

NOTE : I am inputing these values with space between them and then in the code I do this:

```
string input = ReadInput();
string values [] = input.split(' ')
```

I'm tryining to figure out how could I do this without splitting on space?

How could I make it work if I input the values like:

```
FRBL
```

My original attempt works fine but I was curious on how I could do it in another way and I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just treat your string as an array of `char` values. Remove any spaces an use `ToArray()`:

```
string input = ReadInput();
var moves = input.Replace(" ", "").ToCharArray();

foreach(char move in moves)
{
    switch(move)
    {
        case 'F': 
            MoveForwards();
            break;
        case 'R': 
            MoveBackwards();
            break;
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: @JacobKrall You were seconds ahead of me :)

Comment: You wouldn't believe the time i spent searching for this. Sometimes it is just that simple. Thank you!

Comment: No need for `ToCharArray` since `string` is already an `IEnumerable<char>`

Answer (score 4):

No need to split strings, just `foreach` through the source string and look at it character by character:

```
foreach (char c in input) {
   switch (c) {
       case 'F':
          //do something;
          break;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for loop to iterate over every character:

```
string input = ReadInput();
char values[] = new string[input.Length]
for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    values[i] = input[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other people have said, you can treat your string instead as an array of characters, so you don't need to worry about splitting the string.

On the other hand, you could also read the character input directly using `Console.ReadKey`:

```
while(true)
{
    var key = Console.ReadKey();

    switch (key.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.F:
            // Handle 'F'
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.R:
            // Handle 'R'
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.B:
            // Handle 'B'
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.L:
            // Handle 'L'
            break;
    }
}
```